# How to add probability to evaluate a Behaviour Tree node?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tree, artificial-intelligence, game-development

I'm working on a game in Unity and decided to use BehaviorTrees to manage the enemy AI.
One of the enemies has the ability to dodge the player's attack. However, this ability should only happen a few times, so I thought about making it occur based on a probability.
It might be possible to do this using a Cooldown as well. But I am facing difficulties in implementing it both ways.

To implement the tree I created the following scripts:
*Node.cs*

```
public enum NodeState
    {
        RUNNING,
        SUCCESS,
        FAILURE
    }

    public class Node
    {

        protected NodeState state;

        public Node parent;
        protected List<Node> children = new List<Node>();

        private Dictionary<string, object> dataContext = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        public Node()
        {
            parent = null;
        }

        public Node(List<Node> children)
        {
            foreach (Node child in children)
            {
                Attach(child);
            }
        }

        private void Attach(Node node)
        {
            node.parent = this;
            children.Add(node);
        }

        public virtual NodeState Evaluate() => NodeState.FAILURE;

            public void SetData(string key, object value)
        {
            dataContext[key] = value;
        }

        public object GetData(string key)
        {
            object value = null;

            if (dataContext.TryGetValue(key, out value))
                return value;

            Node node = parent;

            while (node != null)
            {
                value = node.GetData(key);
            
                if (value != null)
                    return value;
            
                node = node.parent;
            }

            return null;
        }
    
        public bool ClearData(string key)
        {

            if (dataContext.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                dataContext.Remove(key);
                return true;
            }

            Node node = parent;

            while (node != null)
            {
                bool cleared = node.ClearData(key);
            
                if (cleared)
                    return true;
            
                node = node.parent;
            }

            return false;
        }

    }
```

---

*Tree.cs*

```
public abstract class Tree : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Node root = null;

        public virtual void Start()
        {
            root = SetupTree();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (root != null)
            {
                root.Evaluate();
            }
        }

        protected abstract Node SetupTree();
    }
```

---

I also implemented some other classes that derive from node, such as *Selector.cs* and *Sequence.cs*
To create a node that depends on a probability, I thought about creating another class that derives from the node, as follows:

```
public class Probability : Node
{
    private Node child;
    private float probability;
    
    public Probability(Node child, float probability)
    {
        this.child = child;
        this.probability = probability;
    }

    public override NodeState Evaluate()
    {
        if (probability <= Random.value)
        { 
            return child.Evaluate();
        }

        return NodeState.FAILURE;
    }
}
```

I'm using these classes as follows in the enemy controller:
*EnemySwordmasterBT.cs*

```
public class EnemySwordmasterBT : EnemyBT
{
    
    [SerializeField] public float evasionDistance = 2f;
    [SerializeField] public float evasionProbability = 0.3f;

    protected override Node SetupTree()
    {
        
        Node root = new Selector(new List<Node>
        {
            new Sequence(new List<Node>
            {
                new CheckTargetAttacking(Player.Instance.GetHolder().GetHoldableObject().GetComponent<IWeapon>()),
                new Probability(new TaskEvade(targetTransform, movementNavMesh, evasionDistance), evasionProbability),
            }),
            new Sequence(new List<Node>
            {
                new CheckTargetInAttackRange(transform, targetTransform, attackTargetDistance),
                new TaskAttack(weapon)
            }),
            new Sequence(new List<Node>
            {
                new CheckIsNotAttacking(weapon),
                new TaskChase(targetTransform, movementNavMesh)
            })
        });

        return root;
    }
}
```

But as the *Evaluate()* method runs in an *Update()*, it generates several random numbers per frame. That's why the dodge action, TaskEvade, always happens.

And I'm having trouble solving this problem.

So I would like to ask for help to solve this problem. Any tips to improve my current design would also be appreciated =)

I also tried some solutions using the cooldown idea, but so the question doesn't get too big I won't add them yet. But if you find it relevant, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To address the issue with your Probability node always triggering, you need to generate the random number only once per decision-making cycle and use that number consistently for all probability-based nodes.

What you could try is to generate a random number once: In your Tree class, generate a single random number at the start of each decision-making cycle. This random number will be shared among all probability-based nodes in the tree during that cycle.

```
public class Tree : MonoBehaviour
    {
    private Node root = null;
    private float randomValue;

    public virtual void Start()
    {
        root = SetupTree();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        randomValue = Random.value; // Generate a random number for this decision-making cycle

        if (root != null)
        {
            root.Evaluate();
        }
    }

    // Rest of your Tree class...
}
```

Use the Same Random Number: Modify your Probability node to use the shared random number generated at the start of the decision-making cycle.

```
public class Probability : Node
{
    private Node child;
    private float probability;

    public Probability(Node child, float probability)
    {
        this.child = child;
        this.probability = probability;
    }

    public override NodeState Evaluate()
    {
        if (probability <= randomValue) // Use the random number generated in the Tree class
        {
            return child.Evaluate();
        }

        return NodeState.FAILURE;
    }
}
```

By generating the random number once per decision-making cycle, you ensure that all probability-based nodes in your tree use the same random value for their evaluations. This approach should help prevent the dodge action from happening in every frame and make it occur based on the specified probability.

Let me know if this works!

Comment: Please note that this chat GPT answer...

Comment: I tried implementing your solution, DustyKrumples, but I had the same problem as before. If I did it right, even with the random number in the tree's Update() method, it runs several times and the evasion is always performed.

Comment: @Selvin, I tried using GPT to solve my problem, but I couldn't get a satisfactory answer. The chat always tells me to add a control variable to make Probability run only once, but this makes it only run once during the entire Game. That's why I thought that maybe using _Probability_ together with _Cooldown_ would be the solution to this problem.